# protobuffer (protoc) Generate file(.h/.cc) too big

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I want use the Protobuffer in the Android, but when I use the protoc.exe generate test.proto file of the test.pb.h/test.pb.cc file, they size is to big , I already write the

```
option optimize_for = CODE_SIZE;    or   option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;
```

in the test.proto file. but generate file still to big, How Can I do it?

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, the size is too big?  Too big for what?

Comment: for libprotobuf-lite.a / or for test.pb.h,test.pb.cc

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are having.  Why does it matter if the output is big?

Comment: For example, I used protoc.exe generated a test.pb.h and test.pb.cc, test.pb.h file size of 19K, test.pb.cc file size of 26K, because our projects in generation there are many. pb.h and. pb.cc files, so causing APK file is large, so I want to generate test.pb.h and test.pb.cc file size can be smaller, for example test.pb.h only 1K , test.pb.cc only 2K.

Comment: who can help me, thanks~~~~god

Comment: The only way to make the files smaller is to define smaller/fewer messages.  Or maybe you could try using one of the other protobuf implementations, like the C implementation.

Comment: If I do not use protoc generated. Pb.h and. Pb.cc, can be resolved directly in the code. Proto files? Or can I remove some redundant generation options, in protoc.exe code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  There are no options other than `optimize_for` that will magically reduce code size for you.